# Sonata, Symfony, Password Encryption, Doctrine Listerner/Subscriber

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, password-encryption, sonata

- Infos : I'm new to Symfony and Sonata
- My objective : Encrypte the password only for the database side. I would be able to display this password in clear. All this for the field **password** in the entity **Service**.

  - What did i'm trying ? : I tryed to create a Doctrine Listener which use `bcrypt` encryption

    security:

    encoders:
    App\Entity\Service: bcrypt

---

here is the HashPasswordLisetener.php in my App\Doctrine (in the $formMapper of my configureFormField function in App\Admin\ServiceAdmin.php i have a row like this             `->add('password')`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use App\Entity\Service;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class HashPasswordListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof Service) {
            return;
        }
        $this->encodePassword($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof Service) {
            return;
        }
        $this->encodePassword($entity);

        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
        $em->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['prePersist', 'preUpdate'];
    }

    /**
     * @param Service $entity
     */
    private function encodePassword(Service $entity)
    {
        if (!$entity->getPlainPassword()) {
            return;
        }
        $encoded = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
            $entity,
            $entity->getPlainPassword()
        );
        $entity->setPassword($encoded);
    }
}
```

---

here is the Service entity in the App\Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use App\Repository\ServiceRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ServiceRepository::class)
 */
class Service implements UserInterface
{

    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true, length=255)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $identifier;

    private $plainPassword;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setComment(?string $comment): self
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdentifier(): ?string
    {
        return $this->identifier;
    }

    public function setIdentifier(string $identifier): self
    {
        $this->identifier = $identifier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword): void
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
        $this->password = null;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->identifier;
    }
}
```

Also my sonata_admin.yaml :

```
app.doctrine.hash_password_listener:
    class: App\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener
    autowire : true
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: 'default' }
```

---

- The result it give me :
  [image]
- My Probleme :
  **I understand the function encodePassword is waiting for a UserInterface in 1st arg (instead of my entity) and the password to encrypt in 2nd arg** but i don't understand who use this UserInterface ? Where i'm suppose to call it ? to get it ? to send it ?

I think i give lot of details but if i forgot something feel free to notice me ^^
Thanks the time you spend at least reading.

Comment: `UserInterface` is used all over the [auth system](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#entity-user-provider). Just make your `Service` entity implement it. But if you don't want to, you can use `PasswordEncoder` instead of `UserPasswordEncoder`, see `EncoderFactory`.

Comment: ok i will try ty

Comment: @msg , I implement User-Interface and i added `eraseCredentials()` `getSalt()` `getRoles()` but here is the error 
 .........................................................................................................................................................................]    
`Cannot autowire service "app.doctrine.hash_password_listener": argument "$passwordEncoder" of method "App\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener::__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder" but no such service exists.`

Comment: Typehint it as `UserPasswordEncoderInterface`, as you had it before.

Comment: I have  a new error : `Class App\Entity\Service contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\..\UserInterface::getUsername)`......... But i don't have username i'm a bit confuse sry for asking a lot of beginner question @msg

Comment: That's not necessarily the `username` field, just a way to uniquely identify the user account. I'm guessing that in your case, just remove the `abstract` keyword and make it `return $this->identifier;`.

Comment: i do not have error anymore, i can create a new service and update it but i checked phpmyadmin and the password is absolutly not encrypted (i will edite my question with the new code version)

Comment: Are you certain that the listener is being called? On the other hand, `setPassword` should only be called by the listener, there _should_ be no way to end up with a plaintext password in there, is your form mapping correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223096/discussion-between-halfa-and-msg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a probleme but i was coding an **Hashing** type of code but i was looking for an encrypting methode. but here is how i deal for having a working hashing :

- Step 1 : implementing *UserInterface* in my Service entity
- Step 2 : Replace *UserPasswordEncoder* for *UserPasswordEncoderInterface* in the Listener
- Step 2.5 : Added all function needed for the `UserInterface` like `eraseCredidential` `getSalt()`.. see : [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html) for more details
- Step 3 : Adding a `getUsername` which `return this->identifier`
- Step 4 : using `plainPasswords` in form field instead of `password`
- Step 5 : added a provider :

  app_user:

  ```
    entity:
    class: 'App\Entity\Service'
    property: 'identifier'
  ```
- Step 6 : Using `TextType::class` for `plainPassword` form field type + fixing the `use` with :
  *Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType*
- Step 7 : Working

(Special thanks to @msg who helped me a lot)